# Convert mm:ss and hh:mm to a timestamp in php

Tags: php

How can I convert a string, such as 02:00 to a timestamp that can be saved into the databse as an integer? It can either be mm:ss or hh:mm depending on what I want the user to input in the form. But it's always either mm:ss or hh:mm

`strtotime` delivers unreliable results, so I figured it's not the right way to go. Is there another way I'm not aware of?

**EDIT**

To ask the question in a better way:
I have a form that has an input for mm:ss and an input for hh:mm values. I need to convert these values to unix timestamps. Obviously strtotime is not the way to go for this.

Comment: So what is the timestamp for `02:00` - 120?

Comment: You will have to handle both cases separately since there is no way to distinguish `hh:mm` from `mm:ss`. Your best bet is probably extracting both segments using a regular expression and then converting to seconds.

Comment: `strtotime delivers unreliable results` That's not unreliable, it's because strtotime doesn't play guessing games

Comment: Chris, this will be no issue as the values come from different inputs.

Comment: Mark Baker, yeah true, I worded that stupidly

Comment: u_mulder no, it should be a unix timestamp

Comment: Unix timestamp tells how much seconds passed since certain date. So for proper timestamp you need a date, a full date - year, month,day. Do you have them?

Comment: u_mulder hmmm, no, the user just has to input the mm:ss values and in another field the hh:mm values. I would output these values with `date('i:s', $time);` and `date('H:i', $time);` respectively. Is that a bad way to do it?

Comment: Please read again the definition of a `timestamp`.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, my issue is another, it seems. I should save the two values in a `time` field and then go from there, I guess. I was completely oblivous of the `time` datatype. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant convert only minutes or hours to timestamp, you need to have a date. In php you can use mktime function:

```
$time = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds, $month, $day, $year);
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

For example you have hh:mm input

```
$input = '02:15';

$arr = array_map('intval', explode(':', $input));

// Create timestamp with selected time for today date
$time = mktime($arr[0], $arr[1], 1, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
```

Comment: so, like, explode for example the 02:00 and then use mktime() with the respective values?

Comment: I think I should save the values into a `time` field in the database... I guess that would be the proper way to go.